# Why does File.open not read and write in relative directory when using shebang?

Tags: ruby

I have following code

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative 'parser'
Parser.new
```

When I call File.open it does not read and write in its relative directory as it normally would why is this the case? For example if I go into terminal and call my Parser class there File.open behaves normally, reading and writing from its relative directory.

Here is the Parser class

```
require_relative 'HPC'

class Parser
    def initialize
        o = File.open('O.txt','a+')
        i = File.open("here.txt",'r').readlines


        i.each do |line|
            code, pcum, div, frank = line.split
            hypo_price = HPC::hpc(pcum, div, frank)
            o.puts "#{code}: #{hypo_price}"
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code with the problematic `File.open`? All I see are 3 not so important lines

Comment: Thank you, so `O.txt` is in the same directory as the script and you want to open it is the question?

Comment: yes O.txt and here.txt is in the same directory as the script but when I run the first 3 lines of code an error appears saying it cannot find here.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File.open` opens a file from your current directory. To set a path relative to the script, try this:

```
here_path = File.expand_path("here.txt", File.dirname(__FILE__))
i = File.open(here_path,'r').readlines
```